# Multiple Vertical Stepper Components - Vuetify Issue

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, uistepper

I am trying to put multiple vertical stepper components on a single page. The individual steps are inheriting the same "step" from the e6 data return and showing the same information on all steppers.

Has anyone been successful at using multiple steppers without this issue or know a work around?

Comment: please share the code ans explain more your issue

Comment: Code Below. The issue is that all of the steppers are pulling the last "e6" step's v-card input. I've updated the numbers of the steppers, tried assigning different e6 id's but same issue still:

Comment: <v-stepper v-model="e6" vertical>
              <v-stepper-step :complete="e6 > 1" step="1">
                Step One
              </v-stepper-step>

              <v-stepper-content step="1">
                <v-card
                  color="grey lighten-3"
                  class="mb-12"
                  height="200px"
                  style="color: #000; padding: 10px; font-weight: 500"
                >

Comment: <v-stepper-content step="2">
                <v-card
                  color="grey lighten-3"
                  class="mb-12"
                  height="200px"
                  style="color: #000; padding: 10px; font-weight: 500"
                >

Comment: data() {
    return {
      e6: 1,
      dialog: false,
    }